# WinUI 3 How to Bind Command to ViewModel property when using a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, winui-3

I am using a `Grid` called `MainGrid` to position an `ItemsRepeater` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` within my `ViewModel`.

```
<muxc:ItemsRepeater
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Molts}"
    Layout="{StaticResource VerticalStackLayout}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MoltTemplate}">
</muxc:ItemsRepeater>
```

I have created a `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MoltTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Command="{Binding DisplayAvailAIsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}">Add</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

which has a `TextBox` and `Button`. I want the `Button` to fire a command in my `ViewModel` but items within the `ItemsRepeater` have their `DataContext` set to their `Model` class and not the `ViewModel`. [I found this post](https://www.kevindockx.com/mvvm-challenge-binding-to-a-command-from-inside-an-itemscontrol-datatemplate/) which states that I can change the `Command` of my `Button` to set the `DataContext` to my `ViewModel` by setting `ElementName` to a UI element that has as its `DataContext` the `ViewModel`

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayAvailAIsCommand, ElementName=MainGrid}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}">Add</Button>
```

The constructor of my window sets the `DataContext` of the `MainGrid` like this

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MainGrid.DataContext = new MoltViewModel();
}
```

However, this does not work and the command does not fire. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an attached property that sets the `DataContext` of the `Button` to a parent element of a specific type such as for example `ItemsRepeater`:

```
public static class AncestorSource
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AncestorTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AncestorType",
            typeof(Type),
            typeof(AncestorSource),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(Type), OnAncestorTypeChanged)
    );

    public static void SetAncestorType(FrameworkElement element, Type value) =>
        element.SetValue(AncestorTypeProperty, value);

    public static Type GetAncestorType(FrameworkElement element) =>
        (Type)element.GetValue(AncestorTypeProperty);

    private static void OnAncestorTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement target = (FrameworkElement)d;
        if (target.IsLoaded)
            SetDataContext(target);
        else
            target.Loaded += OnTargetLoaded;
    }

    private static void OnTargetLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement target = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        target.Loaded -= OnTargetLoaded;
        SetDataContext(target);
    }

    private static void SetDataContext(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        Type ancestorType = GetAncestorType(target);
        if (ancestorType != null)
            target.DataContext = FindParent(target, ancestorType);
    }

    private static object FindParent(DependencyObject dependencyObject, Type ancestorType)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        if (ancestorType.IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType()))
            return parent;

        return FindParent(parent, ancestorType);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MoltTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
        <Button local:AncestorSource.AncestorType="muxc:ItemsRepeater"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayAvailAIsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}">Add</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2022/01/20/bind-to-a-parent-element-in-winui-3/) for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure either of these work? I need to pass the TextBox value to the command

Comment: @darylnak: Please see my updated answer for an example of how you could do this using an attached property.