# Can I bind to a view model from within a DataTemplate using x:Bind?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3

Bare minimum example:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomTemplate" x:DataType="data:CustomType">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Foo}" Foreground="{x:Bind viewModel.GetColor(Foo), Mode=OneWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Bar}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

In this code, the `viewModel` cannot be found because the data template is looking for a `viewModel` within `CustomType`. This uses [a feature of x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings) which allows functions to be used in bindings. This means that I can't use `RelativeSource` with a `Binding` to set the path where the binding looks for `viewModel` (though I couldn't get it to work even without the function).

There are workarounds that would be pretty easy. For example, since `CustomType` is an `ObservableObject` it's no problem to just create a `Color` property which the binding can read directly, but because `CustomType` is just a data type it shouldn't care about what's going on in the UI side of things at all. Alternatively, a wrapper class (`CustomTypeUi` or such) could expose that additional functionality, but a wrapper just for something like this which seems like it should be pretty trivial feels wrong and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Is there an idiomatic approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the `DataTemplate` is a resource of a `Page`, you can `x:Name` your `Page`, **ThisPage** for instance, and then:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisPage, Path=ViewModel.AwesomeString, Mode=OneWay}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

But:

- works with `Binding` but not with `x:Bind`, so cannot call a method.
- works with `ListView` or `GridView` but not with `ItemsRepeater`.

Now, let me show you an example using a value converter. This example relies on that `Foo` is a `string` or that `ToString()` can be used but you might be able to apply it to your case.

```cs
public class  StringToColorDictionary : Dictionary<string, Color>
{
}
```

```cs
public class ObjectToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public StringToColorDictionary Colors { get; set; } = new();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return
            value.ToString() is string stringValue &&
            Colors.TryGetValue(stringValue, out var color)
                ? new SolidColorBrush(color)
                : new SolidColorBrush(Microsoft.UI.Colors.Transparent);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ObjectToColorConverter x:Key="ObjectToColorConverter">
        <local:ObjectToColorConverter.Colors>
            <local:StringToColorDictionary>
                <Color x:Key="A">Red</Color>
                <Color x:Key="B">Green</Color>
                <Color x:Key="C">Blue</Color>
            </local:StringToColorDictionary>
        </local:ObjectToColorConverter.Colors>
    </local:ObjectToColorConverter>
    <DataTemplate
        x:Key="ItemTemplate"
        x:DataType="local:Item">
        <TextBlock
            Foreground="{x:Bind Foo, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToColorConverter}}"
            Text="{x:Bind Foo}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: For my case, using a converter does work, but since the conversion requires the use of a service, the converter has to reference the service, which doesn't feel great—that's work that should be done by the view model and not shunted to a converter somewhere. Shame that there doesn't seem to be a way to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to bind this [FrameworkElement.DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=winrt-22621) to **view** Element. See @mm8 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703773. But It seems the **view** cannot be [Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4).

My test:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:Customer">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock local:AncestorSource.AncestorType="ListBox" Text="{Binding Tag}" />
            
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and

```
<Window
    x:Class="App2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Customers}" Width="350" Margin="0,5,0,10" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" Tag="aTag"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: This unfortunately requires use of `Binding` over `x:Bind`, which makes using a function not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> This unfortunately requires use of Binding over x:Bind, which makes
> using a function not possible.

@Poyo OK, a new question. Have you checked @mm8 's [BindingToParentElementSample sample](https://github.com/mgnsm/CodeSamples/blob/96c82ac4d098943663c796e0cbb7a290fc0541d2/BindingToParentElementSample/MainWindow.xaml#L25C48-L25C48)?

And I also have my own way to do this. You can set `x:Bind`s' `dataRoot` in your `name.g.cs` file but you must determine which is your `dataRoot` for your `x:Bind`s in the same `DataTemplate`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1465387/generic-xaml-x-bind-with-converter-binding for more information

```
public bool SetDataRoot(global::System.Object newDataRoot)
{
    this.bindingsTracking.ReleaseAllListeners();
    if (newDataRoot != null)
    {
        this.dataRoot = global::WinRT.CastExtensions.As<global::App3.DateRange>(newDataRoot);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Poyo [RelayCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand) could be a workaround for `Binding`. My thought is not applicable because it doesn't resolve the only one data source question.

Answer (score 0):

I've simply resorted to "functional programming" in my "data objects" (x:DataType templates or anywhere else) when confronted with these brain teasers; as in:

```
public string MyAnswer => this.IsFoo ? this.Name : SomethingElse();  // etc.
```

Then "x:Bind" to MyAnswer and / or use it in procedural programming.

Using variations such as "IsThisOrThat => ...", etc. also improves readability.